# how do i release the auto increment serial nos that are missing

Tags: mysql

i have a table with auto increment field and i am using transactions when inserting new data.
now i find there are a few serial nos that are missing. suppose the last serial no was 475, now when i insert new row, the serial allotted to it is 481. how do i correct this.

```
table_A fields ID(Auto increment),Name,Address
table_B fields ID(Auto increment FK TO table_A ID),Tel,Fax,Email,Salesman
table_C fields ID(Auto increment FK TO table_A ID),monthly_commitment

mysql_query("BEGIN");
$a = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_A VALUES('','name','address')");
$b = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_B VALUES('','tel','fax','email','salesman')");
$b = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_C VALUES('','monthly commitment')");
if(($a) && ($b) && ($c)){mysql_query("COMMIT");} else {mysql_query("ROLLBACK");}
```

Comment: you cant. Or you may need to avoid auto-incrementing and calculate the row id yourself

Comment: You could drop and recreate your auto increment column.

Comment: Furthermore you shouldn't. There's a good reason why db designers left it so.

Comment: @Asad that also means he needs to re-insert values upto id = 476. Thankfully he doesnt have a million row right now

Comment: Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3546d/1/. Generally, however, this is not what `auto-increment` is meant for. You should make another column and add logic to your insert statements to ensure that the values in it are consecutive.